# What is a valuable answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow, which has gotten many downvotes, and I would like deleted. The problem is, I can't delete it, because it has answers, so I flagged it for moderator attention, asking them to delete it for me.

My "request" was denied, and the reason given was that they don't delete posts with valuable answers, however, **none** of the answers were upvoted. Out of the two answers given, one was downvoted, and the other has not had any votes. To me, these are not valuable answers, otherwise, the community would have thought so too, and upvoted the answers.

So, what makes answers "valuable" that stops a moderator from deleting a question with these answers, and, should we be able to delete our own answered questions, if none of the answers have upvotes?

Comment: The upvotes/checkmark on the answers is what makes them "valuable" in the eyes of the system.

Comment: Are you referring to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858659/check-if-string-is-valid-date)? It seems that an answer does in fact have upvotes on it.

Comment: @Lix It didn't before... *someone* must've upvoted it

Comment: You could also request to disassociate your account from that post.

Comment: @Lix [answerer's rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/517016/nigel-whatling?tab=reputation) shows that upvote was cast 15 minutes after this question was asked at meta, just about the time that you posted [comment mentioning this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276578/what-is-a-valuable-answer#comment116284_276578)

Comment: The fact that you didn't have to pay anybody to receive help does of course not mean that the time SO users invested in trying to help you was not valuable to them.  Avoid using a site powered by volunteer contributions if this is not obvious to you.

Comment: Is your question really *`What is a valuable answer?`* or *`Why can't I delete my own poor question?`*? Consider editing your title to suit your actual question.

Answer (score 4):

We get dozens of flags a day by people who have questions which received answers that they want to have deleted. We decline the majority of these.

When you ask a question on Stack Overflow, the idea is that your question and the answers to it aren't just for your benefit, but for the many people who might encounter something similar in the future. Deleting a question with good answers deprives those future visitors of a resource that could have helped them.

Not only that, but people volunteered time to answer your question. Deleting your question after they've invested that time in it is disrespectful to those who've answered, and can often cause these volunteers to get quite upset.

For these reasons, there are system-imposed restrictions on when you can delete your question (only when there are no upvoted answers and there are fewer than three answers overall). Unfortunately, the prompt that you are given tells you to flag moderators in that case, without any explanation that we only rarely accept these flags.

Personally, I have a very low bar for what I consider a "valuable" answer when it comes to deletion. I am hesitant to delete on-topic, relevant content posted by a user. If someone invested time in making a legitimate answer to your question and that answer was upvoted or otherwise could be of some small value to someone in the future, I will decline your flag requesting deletion. There are always exceptions (sensitive information being exposed, etc.), but our tendency is to decline these flags.

Comment: people also invest their time by even reading your question... keep that in mind too.